# How to delete new line string from array [JS]

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

here I have some local function which should convert some HTML tags (keys) which contains some values into array. Every ended tag with some product have 2x '\n' which is included into array.

How can I remove breaking line from aray?

```
function cleanCatalog(s){
        const separateValues = /<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g;
        let newLocal = s.replace(separateValues, " ");
        let cleanText = newLocal;
        let catalogArray = [cleanText.split("  ")];
        return catalogArray;
    }
```

output:

> "["drill", "99", "5", "↵↵", "hammer", "10", "50", "↵↵", ...]"

Comment: Just use regular DOM methods to traverse the elements and get their text contents (+ an optional `.trim()`)

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Hello, expected output: "["drill", "99", "5", "hammer", "10", "50", ...]"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `/^\s*$/` regular expression to filter out white-spaces from the array. This can be useful if you have items like `"\n\n"` or `"\t   \n"` and want to filter them too

```js
const arr = ["drill", "99", "5", "\n \t", " ", "hammer", "10", "50", "\n\n"];
const ans = arr.filter(x => !/^\s*$/.test(x));

console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try filtering the array by excluding [new lines](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_newline.asp).

```
const outputWithoutNewLines = output.filter(el => el !== '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to return: return catalogArray.filter(v=>v!='\n');

Comment: You mean like the solution proposed by [Vladimir 10 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54853765/402037)?

Comment: I did not try to get something special here, I got this problem: https://imgur.com/a/nmNjpfK

I can not submit my answer (I tried to indent by 4 spaces), then I deleted everything then post again, it success but you know, I see @vladimir Bogomolov answered.

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter function, I see you have some item with duplicate `/n` charactor, my solution can solve this case:

```
catalogArray.filter(e => e.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "") !== '')
```

ex:

```
["drill", "99", "5", "\n\n", "hammer", "10", "50", "\n\n\n"].filter(e => e.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "") !== '')
// =>  ["drill", "99", "5", "hammer", "10", "50"]
```